# Jquery validator not validating required condition

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validator for form validation. My jquery code is given below

```
$('#formvalidate').validate({
    code: {
        required: false,
        regx: /^\d{5}$/
        },
```

In case my validation is not done, i.e it still validates code and the condition is required as true. When i delete the regex condition then false condition works.

```
$('#formvalidate').validate({
    code: {
        required: false
        },
```

In case validation for required works fine. Can some one explain what is the actual problem and how i can i solve this to get both the conditions work. That is i need to check required= False condition and if some value is entered regex have to be validated. Please help me to get through this problem as i am new in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no such `.validate()` method option called `code`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in the implementation of the `regx` rule(It doesn't look to be from the original library, might be a custom rule)... it has to check whether the value is optional...

you can use the pattern rule from additinal-methods.js

```
$('#formvalidate').validate({
    rules: {
        code: {
            required: false,
            pattern: /^\d{5}$/
        },
    }
```

Comment: How can this possibly do anything when there is no such `.validate()` method option called `code`?